# R: Azure Table entity query via REST call fails

Tags: r, azure, rest, azure-table-storage, databricks

I am working with Azure, Databricks and R. I am trying to call Azure Table Storages from R cell in Databricks notebook via [ATS REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/table-service-rest-api). I am able to create/delete tables and I also can insert new entities into existing tables. However, if I try to query entities I always get an 403 error. Here is my code that tries to filter on "RowKey=1" and select "Name" property.

```
 library(httr)

 key <- "myStorageKey"

 url <- "https://myAccount.table.core.windows.net/myTable()?$filter=(RowKey%20eq%20'1')?$select=Name"

 canonResource <- paste0("/", account, "/myTable()?$filter=(RowKey%20eq%20'1')?$select=Name")
```

Now I am using SharedKeyLite authentiction as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key)

```
 requestdate <- format(Sys.time(),"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z", tz="GMT")    

 signStr <- paste(requestdate, canonResource, sep = "\n") 


  auth <- paste0("SharedKeyLite myAccount:",
             RCurl::base64(digest::hmac(key = RCurl::base64Decode(key, mode = "raw"),
                                        object = enc2utf8(signStr),
                                        algo = "sha256", raw = TRUE)))
```

Now, according to the [query entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-entities) description, i need to form a header like that:

```
   header <- httr::add_headers(#`x-ms-version` = "2015-12-11 ",
                                `x-ms-date` = requestdate,  
                                 Authorization = auth,
                                #Accept = "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                                #`Accept-Charset` = "UTF-8",
                                 DataServiceVersion = "3.0;NetFx",
                                #Date = requestdate,
                                 MaxDataServiceVersion = "3.0;NetFx")
```

However, calling

```
 httr::GET(url = url, config = header, verbose())
```

gives me

```
  HTTP/1.1 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
```

Does anyone see what I am missing or doing wrong? I played around with the header un-/commenting out several optional ones, but it still fails. As said, other calls on that api work for me. What I find a bit confusing is, that the documentation of the query call say I must specify the (Max)DataServiceVersion header, even if it is an optional header!

Comment: Your `url` variable has the table name as `myTable` whereas in `canonResource`, it is `users`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Also your query string should be `$filter=(RowKey%20eq%20"1")&select=Name`

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far! The first was actually just a typo. The second I adjusted without success, unfortunately. How about the header, are those in correct form; especially the DataService ones? Do you see any other issue here? Does above code work for anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with how you're creating your `canonResource`.

Based on the [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key):

> **Shared Key Lite and Table service format for 2009-09-19 and later**
>
> This format supports Shared Key and Shared Key Lite for all versions
>   of the Table service, and Shared Key Lite for version 2009-09-19 and
>   later of the Blob and Queue services and version 2014-02-14 and later
>   of the File service. This format is identical to that used with
>   previous versions of the storage services. Construct the
>   CanonicalizedResource string in this format as follows:
>
> Beginning with an empty string (""), append a forward slash (/),
>   followed by the name of the account that owns the resource being
>   accessed.
>
> Append the resource's encoded URI path. If the request URI addresses a
>   component of the resource, append the appropriate query string. **The
>   query string should include the question mark and the comp parameter
>   (for example, ?comp=metadata). No other parameters should be included
>   on the query string.**

Based on this, your `canonResource` should be

```
canonResource <- paste0("/", account, "/myTable()")
```

Here's the complete code I used:

```
library(httr)
library(RCurl)
library(digest)

key <- "<account-key>"

    account <- "<account-name>"

    url <- "https://<account-name>.table.core.windows.net/myTable()?$filter=RowKey%20eq%20'1'&$select=Name"

    canonResource <- paste0("/", account, "/myTable()")

    print(canonResource)

    requestdate <- format(Sys.time(),"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z", tz="GMT")

    print(requestdate)

    signStr <- paste(requestdate, canonResource, sep = "\n") 

    print(signStr)

    auth <- paste0("SharedKeyLite ", account, ":",
                 RCurl::base64(digest::hmac(key = RCurl::base64Decode(key, mode = "raw"),
                                            object = enc2utf8(signStr),
                                            algo = "sha256", raw = TRUE)))

    print(auth)

    header <- httr::add_headers(`x-ms-version` = "2015-12-11 ",
                                    `x-ms-date` = requestdate,  
                                     Authorization = auth,
                                    Accept = "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                                    #`Accept-Charset` = "UTF-8",
                                     DataServiceVersion = "3.0;NetFx",
                                    #Date = requestdate,
                                     MaxDataServiceVersion = "3.0;NetFx")

    print(header)

    httr::GET(url = url, config = header, verbose())
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot! Seems that my major misstake was the cononicalized resource.